# DataSet didn't return any row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net, dataset

i dont know why my methods for dataset with parameters don't work,
can someone debug or explain why my codes return nothing.

here's my code for dataset

```
public DataSet executeDataSet(String sql, Dictionary<String, Object> parameters)
{
   try
   {
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> row in parameters)
      {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(row.Key, row.Value);
      }
      ds = new DataSet();
      adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                
      adapter.Fill(ds);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      }
      return ds;
}
```

and here's the code to call the method in my DAL that will load the data in my datagridview called dataGrid_SessionType

```
public void loadData(string sql, Dictionary<string,object> param)
{

   DAL dal = new DAL(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SADConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds = dal.executeDataSet(sql,param);
   try
   {
      dataGrid_SessionType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

and here's another method that will call loadData() and will pass the parameters needed

```
private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
   string sql = "Select SessionType_ID as ID, SessionType_Name as 'Session Name', SessionType_Desc as 'Session Description', Status from SessionType WHERE Status = 'Available' and SessionType_Name LIKE '@1'";
   Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   param.Add("@1",txtbox_Search.Text+"%");
   loadData(sql, param);
   txtbox_Search.Clear();
}
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Well we don't know what data you've got, or what the textbox contains, which makes it hard to help you...

Comment: sory, i forgot to include that, im currently building a search function for my program where i search for the table name SessionType
the data currently input at the txtbox_Search is search info

Comment: @Steve my connection string is currently declared in my app.config
here's my connection string:
<add name="SADConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=LAUDE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the parameter placeholder surrounded by single quotes. In that way you transform the placeholder in a literal string. And your query cannot find any row where the `SessionType_Name` field contains the string @1.
You should remove the single quotes around the parameter placeholder.

```
string sql = @"Select SessionType_ID as ID, SessionType_Name as 'Session Name', 
               SessionType_Desc as 'Session Description', Status from SessionType 
               WHERE Status = 'Available' and SessionType_Name LIKE @1";
```

Comment: well , i tried your code but the LIKE operator need the single quotation and i try to concatenate it in my parameter like this one
param.Add("@1","**'"+txtbox_Search.Text+"%'**"); but it still didn't return my expecting result

Comment: One of the many benefits in using a parameterized query is you don't put any quotes. Neither in the command text neither in the parameter value. I suggest to use the debugger to see what value is passed as parameter value

Comment: @steve your right, i remove the quotation mark at my parameters and it works fine thanks now i just need to debug and try if it is prone to SQL injection